# Is there a way to tap a pin on a map with Xamarin.UITest to test if it gets clicked?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, nunit, mapbox

I am writing test cases for a xamarin app. I am currently working on a Xamarin project that is using MapBox. I need to be able to test tapping on a pin that is on the map. I see that Xamarin.UITest allows you to TapCoordinates(x, y) but that is not working. I need the pin to pop up an overlay, which it does just fine in the iOS simulator when I click on it. How is TapCoordinates() different?

Answer (score 0):

TapCoordinates is not part of NUnit. It's part of Xamarin.UiTest. It doesn't test anything, it **does** something with your app. Specifically, it simulates the user tapping at a certain location.

If you want to test something with NUnit, you would usually test whatever it is you expect to happen as a result of tapping the pin.

many people seem to write UI tests without any NUnit assertions. They consider their test to pass if no exceptions are thrown.

You can probably get a better answer if you specify what it is you want to test, that is, what should happen as a result of tapping.

Comment: Sorry I should have phrased my question better. I am using both NUnit and Xamarin.UiTest. I would like to mimic tapping on the pin so that the UI displays a pop up which, in turn, I would like to simulate. I need to automate UI Tests for the variety of devices out there

Comment: Somebody with more knowledge of Xamarin UiTest will have to answer, but it sounds like you want to verify that a particular event is generated when you tap. As a general rule, I always test the generation of events and their handling separately.

Comment: Alright have changed from trying to tap on the pin to invoking the method that should be called when the pin is tapped on with a backdoor call exactly like this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/
My app now crashes when it gets to the backdoor method

Answer (score 0):

So I had to create a backdoor method on the Android main activity and the iOS app delegate. Then I had to pass a notification to the same method that gets called when a pin gets tapped something similar to the following code:

```
  NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("tapPin", TapPin);

  public void TapPin(NSNotification notification)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Tap Pin is being called by " + notification.Object.ToString());
  }
```

Then add this method in the App delegate

```
   [Export("myBackdoorMethod:")] // notice the colon at the end of the method name
public NSString MyBackdoorMethod(NSString value)
{
   NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("tapPin", this);
}
```